# Epsilon delta proofs of theorems of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Can anyone suggest a book which contains epsilon delta prooves for properties and theorems of continuity rather than sequential proofs.

Comment: Ummm, every calculus book written in the last 100 years?

Comment: What is a "sequential" proof? How many theorems need epsilon-delta proofs--_all_ of the theorems, or are you allowed to use theorems already proved with epsilon-delta in order to prove other theorems?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Except the ones based on nonstandard analysis :)

Comment: many books use properties of sequences to proove theorems of continuity however epsilon delta proves are different and more complicated

Answer (score 1):

The best book (in my opinion) to learn properly the $\delta-\varepsilon$ definitions of continuity (and convergence of sequences etc) is

Michael Spivak, *Calculus*.